# Pythonではクラスをリストのように扱えるのでしょうか？

Tags: python, python3

Pythonのクラスはリストのように扱えるのでしょうか?`print(s)`でインスタンスオブジェクトが返されそうなのになぜでしょうか？ クラスの引数に`list`をするとこのような動作をするのでしょうか？

引用元:
「独習Python」 P.423

> ```
> class MyStack(list):
>   def push(self, elem):
>       self.append(elem)
>   
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>   s = MyStack([10, 20, 30])
>   s.push(40)
>   print(s.pop())
>   print(s)
>
> # 実行結果
> 40
> [10, 20, 30]
> ```

Comment: `class MyStack(list)` としているので `MyStack` クラスは `list` クラスを継承している事になるのですが、このコードはどこから持ってきたのですか？

Comment: 独習Pythonという本に書かれていました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> クラスの引数にlistをするとこのような動作をするのでしょうか？

`class MyStack(list):` というコードと、 `MyStack([10, 20, 30])`というコードは違う意味を持ってます。

`class MyStack(list):` の方はlistクラスを継承した「MyStack」というクラスの宣言です。
これによりlistと同じふるまいをもったMyStackクラスが定義されます。

`MyStack([10, 20, 30])`の方は、MyStackクラスのインスタンスを生成しています。
そのときにlistオブジェクトをMyStack生成時の引数に渡しています。これは継承元のlistで定義された振る舞いです。

以下はlistクラスの生成時(コンストラクタ)についての説明です。
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists

> コンストラクタは、 iterable の項目と同じ項目で同じ順のリストを構築します。 iterable は、シーケンス、イテレートをサポートするコンテナ、またはイテレータオブジェクトです。 iterable が既にリストなら、 iterable[:] と同様にコピーが作られて返されます。

MyStackクラスはlistを継承しているので、同じようにコンストラクタの引数にlistを渡すことで、渡されたlistをコピーして生成されます。

Comment: 説明が難しく混乱しているのですが、`MyStack([10, 20, 30])`で渡されたリストオブジェクトは継承されたlistクラスのinitの引数として処理されるということでしょうか？

Comment: はい。 MyStackはlistを継承した型なので、listと同じように振る舞います。

`l = list([1,2,3])`で生成するのと同じように、MyStackも振る舞うようになります。 `ms = MyStack([1,2,3])`

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

> Pythonのクラスはリストのように扱えるのでしょうか?

MyStackはlistを継承したクラスなので、リストのように振る舞いますが、listを継承しなければリストのようには扱えません。

> print(s)でインスタンスオブジェクトが返されそうなのになぜでしょうか？

MyStackのインスタンスオブジェクトが返されています。
type(s)を実行すると、返ってきたインスタンスのクラスがMyStackであることがわかります。

```
<class '__main__.MyStack'>
```

> クラスの引数にlistをするとこのような動作をするのでしょうか？

クラスを定義するとき、クラスの仮引数にクラスを指定するとそのクラスを継承し、継承元のクラスのようにふるまいます。
MyStackはpushメソッドを追加したlistクラスといえます。

Comment: 分かりやすい説明ありがとうございます。